# Why my char* is changing without reason?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Details:

Im using this github project to convert a Json to an object.

https://github.com/ereilin/qt-json

With this json:

```
{
    "bin": "/home/pablo/milaoserver/compile/Devices01.olk",
    "temp":"/home/pablo/milaoserver/temporal/",
    "port": "1234",
    "name": "lekta",

}
```

with this two lines I create two char pointers:

```
 char* bin = configuration["bin"].toString().toLatin1().data();
 char* temp = configuration["temp"].toString().toLatin1().data();
```

Debugging the app I have the proper strings.

However when I use them, concretely the "bin" char changes to

```
`hom
```

Any Idea?

SOLUTION IN COMMENTS:

The problem was the "persistence" of the data.

I found the solution with:

```
std::string binAux(configuration["bin"].toString().toLatin1().data());
std::string tempAux(configuration["temp"].toString().toLatin1().data());

char* bin = new char[binAux.size()+1] ;
strcpy(bin, binAux.c_str());

char* temp = new char[tempAux.size()+1] ;
strcpy(temp, tempAux.c_str());
```

Comment: Is it possible that `toString` produces a temporary string, that doesn't "exist" after the line is finished?

Comment: Does the value of `temp` appear correct?

Comment: Temp exists properly. And the bin too. But when I "use" them, only bin changes :S

Comment: If you're using C++ and Qt, you should use std::string or QString, and not the raw char array.

Comment: I Tried to delete "weird" characters like '.' and '_' but It doesnt work.

Comment: C++ is not Java.  C strings are not Java Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error here is because of temporary object.

`toString()` create a temporary object no longer available after the semicolon.

The standard state :

> 12.2 Temporary objects [class.temporary]
>
> 3/ [...] **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression** (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

That is, when you want to access it you have *Undefined Behavior*.

This should solve your problem :

```
QString str = configuration["bin"].toString().toLatin1();
QByteArray ba = str1.toLatin1();
char *bin = ba.data();
```

But what do you want to use `char*` ? You are in C++, use `std::string` or `Qstring` instead :

```
#include <string>

std::string bin(configuration["bin"].toString().toLatin1().data());
```

Comment: I want to use char* because I'm integrating a C Library that needs char* Thats the problem. Force to change old coders its really difficult. I have seen "ugly code of old people" that you can't imagine :P

Answer (score 0):

Can you please  try something like

```
std::string sbin(configuration["bin"].toString().toLatin1().data());
std::string sTemp(configuration["temp"].toString().toLatin1().data());
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` creates a `QString` object that is deleted immediately, so the data that is contained in it will be freed. I do recommend you to store the data in a `QString` until you use that `char* bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution could be shorter, like this:

```
char* bin = strdup(configuration["bin"].toString().toLatin1().data().c_str());
char* temp = strdup(configuration["temp"].toString().toLatin1().data().c_str());
```

`strdup()` does virtually all you do.